# CSS Two Divs Affect Eachothers Children

Tags: css

I have a `.logo` div on my site which contains `.icon` and `.text`. It also contains `.links`, which is under the `.text` but not part of the actual logo image. Both `.icon` and `.text` have children `.image` and `.image-hover` which I use to make a background-image fade effect (for the logo).

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="icon"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
    <div class="text"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon:hover .image {
    opacity: 0;
}
// opposite for .image-hover

.text:hover .image {
    opacity: 0;
}
// opposite for .image-hover
```

The issue is that the icon and text are independent, making it seem rather ugly. I don't want `.links` to affect (so `.logo:hover` can't be used). Is it possible to make `.icon:hover` affect `.text .image` and vice-versa?

http://jsfiddle.net/7kj7G/

**EDIT**
I have already tried JSW189's suggestion. The `.links` are under `.text` and `.icon` is the same height as both. If I try wrap them the box is only the size of `.text` and doesn't include the full `.icon`.

**EDIT**
It seems the issue with JSW189's suggestion was only the z-index of .icon making the box smaller.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle for the issue.

Comment: you want to simulate `.icon:hover` when you hover instead `.text`? you cant with pure css

Comment: @wes I dont want to simulate `.icon:hover` but I want to affect `.icon .image` AND `.text .image`

Comment: @nebkat Are you opposed to using javascript?

Comment: @JSW189 I'd rather go for your idea than JS

Comment: regarding EDIT: If the `.icon` is floated or absolutely positioned, it will be removed from the document flow. If it's floated, try adding `.wrap-icon-and-text { overflow: hidden; }` (see [Float Containment](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `.icon` and .`text` in another div, and use the `:hover` pseudo-class for that div. That way all the `:hover` styles will appear when the user hovers over either `.icon` or `.text`.

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
    <div class="wrap-icon-and-text">
        <div class="icon"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
        <div class="text"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap-icon-and-text:hover {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: After testing hover with jQuery I had the same issue I mentioned and it turns out it was because of `.icon`s `z-index`. Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="logo">
   <div class="icon"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
   <div class="text"><span class="image"></span><span class="image-hover"></span></div>
   <div class="links">Links</div>
</div>
```

selectors to affect `.icon .image` AND `.text .image` on hover

```
.logo:hover .icon .image
{
    opacity: 0;
}

.logo:hover .text .image
{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want `.links` to affect the hover effect.

Comment: i'm sorry but for me is not clear what you are asking, try to provide a jsfiddle or a image